# How to modify the default `--logdest eventlog` for the Puppet Agent service on Windows?

Tags: windows, logging, service, puppet

I'm running Puppet Agent as a service on Windows but I'm unable to find in the docs how to modify the default behaviour `--logdest eventlog` to `--logdest <FILE>`. I want to have agent logs stored in a file, and not in the Windows Event Log, or better - if that's possible - have them sent back to the Puppet Master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the --logdest to the 'ImagePath' value located in this registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\pe-puppet

We add the switch through puppet code after the agent is installed, meaning that the first run output goes to the event log, but all the subsequent are sent to the local file.  You can also modify the reg key during install through a powershell script.

Comment: I only have `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\puppet` with `ImagePath` containing `"C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\sys\ruby\bin\ruby.exe" -rubygems "C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\service\daemon.rb"` I tried to add `--logdest` and analyzed daemon.rb and tried `--logfile` too, but it's somehow not working...

Comment: My solution was for puppet enterprise agent, looks like open source does this differently. Have you tried using the 'sc config' command as described here: https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/reference/services_agent_windows.html#running-puppet-agent-as-a-service

Comment: Thank you @diavol. Your first answer with modifying the registry seems to work now. Another working method, thanks to the link you posted about `sc` is running: `sc config puppet binPath= "\"C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\sys\ruby\bin\ruby.exe\" -rubygems \"C:\Program Files\Puppet Labs\Puppet\service\daemon.rb\" --logdest c:\puppet-log-test.txt"` which will modify the service startup parameters (which are stored in the registry of course). Problem solved :-)

Comment: That is definitely how you do it now. We've talked about adding the ability to change it